# joomla css for menus and fonts

Tags: joomla-template

if any of you use joomla, could you help me locate the proper code to change for font size, globally, in the ja-purity template.  I also need to adjust the top menu bar width, and the length of each individual menu item in the top bar.  Thank you for assisting me locate this code.

Answer (score 0):

For any properly coded Joomla template (which JA Purity is of course) you will find the CSS files in JOOMLA/templates/template name/css. In this case, there are 4 CSS files for JA Purity. Also keep in mind that some of the template is controlled by the template parameters that can be accessed in the admin my clicking on Template Manager > Ja Purity.

Answer (score 0):

I find the best way to tweak the css in a Joomla template is to use Firefox with the [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) .  Goes something like this.

1. Install Joomla / Template.
2. Open frontend in Firefox with firebug enabled.
3. Use firebug to [inspect](http://getfirebug.com/html) the component you want to tweak.
4. The CSS classes will be displayed on the right.  You can edit the css right there in firebug or use it's handy file / line number links to locate where the css class is defined.